# How does this recursion function in JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

Im learning JS on freecodecamp and am currently on the replace loops with recursion lesson, I almost understand it but the answer they are telling me the sum should end up as I just cant make sense of. So hoping someone could maybe try explain whats happening?

```
function sum(arr, n) {

if (n <= 0) {
  return 0;
} 
else {
  return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
}
}

sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3);
```

Thats the code that is the correct answer, but apparently sum should then equal 9?

Comment: yes the the answer is 9, because you are recusing 4 times,  when you first call it - you pass in 3, as the number of recursions. test in first call  3 > 0, so it calls sum again, but will add current value at n-1 to the returned values from the next call,, and so on - but is decremented the 3 each recursions, until it is <= 0

Comment: ((((0) + 2) + 3) + 4) is 9. What else did you expect? What part exactly is unclear, the parameter `n`?

Comment: if you past your function into the browser debugger you can see better what is going on, by stepping through code - past this into console: 

`function sum(arr, n) {
debugger;

if (n <= 0) {
  return 0;
} 
else {
  return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
}
}`  

then run your function - use F10 to step code

Comment: @Bergi if that was aimed at me then the I obviously understand that equation there equalling 9, but its just trying to figure how the path of the function then ends up with those numbers that i'm struggling with.

Comment: @Rory.Oconnell Do you understand how the call stack works?

Comment: @Bergi I have not covered that yet no, I'll have a little read up see what that is

Comment: @Rory.Oconnell: Just play computer.  This is a small enough example that you should be able to work it out with pencil and paper.  The only thing you need to know about that call stack for this is that when you make a new function call, it gets its own value of the parameters/local variables.  The old ones are restored when you return from it.

Comment: @Rory.Oconnell I guess without knowing that call contexts are getting stacked recursion is really hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

My process of debugging will be first format it so that I will know where loops and conditions start and end. Then write atleast 3 or 4 iterations by hand until I get the flow.

```
function sum(arr, n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
    }
}

sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3);
```

1. sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3);
2. above line will return `sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 2) + 4`
3. above line will return `sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 1) + 3 + 4`
4. above line will return `sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 0) + 2 + 3 + 4`
5. above line will return `0 + 2 + 3 + 4`

It means the answer is **9**

Comment: I kind of get what your saying but still not following fully. When it uses the brackets with  sum(arr, n - 1) does this mean it loops through then? and not just mean minus one of the index value to give array value like arr[n - 1] does? Hopefully you understand what im trying to ask there.

Comment: The first argument of every invocation of sum function is array and is not modified. While the second argument is decremented by 1 every time. I feel that if you write on a paper, you will get more understanding. If you are new to JavaScript or Programming, DM me on twitter, so that we can discuss it more. Twitter user name: [@varundevpro](https://mobile.twitter.com/VarunDevPro). Thanks 